# Using GreenSock to animate gradient change for SVG created dynamically?

Tags: javascript, svg, gradient, gsap

I'm trying to animate a gradient change for a dynamically-created SVG using GreenSock, but am running into more difficulties than expected. There's probably some underlying system architecture I'm not aware of here.

**HTML/CSS** files: nothing is hard-coded here

**JS** file: creates SVG created dynamically

```js
//create an SVG
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");

//alter SVG
svg.setAttribute('width', 500);
svg.setAttribute('height', 500);

//create a rectangle
var rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");

//alter rectangle
rect.setAttribute("stroke", "red");
rect.setAttribute("stroke-width", 10);
rect.setAttribute('x', 150);
rect.setAttribute('y', 100);
rect.setAttribute('width', 200);
rect.setAttribute('height', 300);

//append objects to document
svg.appendChild(rect);
document.body.appendChild(svg);

//animate
gsap.to(rect, {width: 100, height: 100, duration: 3, rotation: 20, ease: "bounce.out"});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.3/gsap.min.js"></script>
```

At this point, we just need to replace `rect`'s background with a gradient and also animate that change. But I have not been able to make this work.

Gradients are defined as:

`var grad1 = "linear-gradient(217deg, rgba(255,0,0,0.9), rgba(255,0,0,0) 70.71%),  linear-gradient(127deg, rgba(0,255,0,0.9), rgba(0,255,0,0) 70.71%), linear-gradient(336deg, rgba(0,0,255,0.9), rgba(0,0,255,0) 70.71%)";`

`var grad2 = "linear-gradient(17deg, rgba(255,0,0,0.7), rgba(255,0,0,0) 70.71%), linear-gradient(200deg, rgba(0,255,0,0.9), rgba(0,255,0,0.2) 70.71%),  linear-gradient(336deg, rgba(0,0,255,0.8), rgba(0,0,255,0.1) 70.71%)";`

`rect.setAttribute`, however, will not accommodate these. `setAttribute("fill", [value])` will work with solid colors, but `setAttribute("background", [value])` or `setAttribute("backgroundImage", [value])` will not work at all.

This [CodePen](https://codepen.io/dfranklinweb/pen/OVWLOd/) does a good job of creating a static gradient for a dynamically created SVG (uses other `<elements>` as well) but I cannot figure out how to animate with GreenSock using this setup. The gradient just stays static.

This [CodePen](https://codepen.io/DickeySingh/pen/LYGXrMq) does a great job of animating the 2 gradients, but uses a `<div>` instead of an SVG. At this point, would it be simpler to somehow rig the `<div>` as a background of the SVG and animate that instead? Is that possible?

What am I missing? Is there a simpler solution that I'm not seeing here? I did not imagine it would be this complicated to move some colors around.

Comment: you need to use SVG linearGradients i.e. markup gradients with SVG. CSS gradients won't work.

Comment: The issue in your code is that you are applying a CSS gradient to a SVG element, but this is not legal.

Here is a working example of animating an SVG gradient: https://www.svgbackgrounds.com/animate-svg-gradients/#:~:text=CSS%20can't%20animate%20gradients%2C%20but%20SVG%20can%20%7C%20SVG%20Backgrounds

Alternatively, you could instead create the rect as a div and then define and animate the gradient using CSS. The article above says that CSS gradients cannot be animated but this is no longer true as support has rolled out, however imo they do not animate as smoothly as SVG gradients do.